# jquery children function stopped working out of the blue - possible depreciation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.10

Ok so I had code on a website which has not changed at all.
Two days ago I was using this functionality and it worked, but then today while I was testing things it just stopped working.

For some reason changing from the `.children()` selector  to `.find()` fixed it which I really wasn't expecting.

Here is the code:

```
var ele = $("div").find("[data-productid='" + response.productId + "']").children(".wishlist-button");
if (response.addedToWishlist) {
    $(ele).children(".button-2.active").removeClass("active");
    $(ele).children(".remove-from-wishlist-button").addClass("active");
}
```

I know that `.children()` only selects immediate child so here is the html which illustrates that:

```
<div class="wishlist-button">
            <input type="button" value="Remove from wishlist" title="Remove from wishlist" class="button-2 remove-from-wishlist-button remove-from-wishlist-button-6475">
            <input type="button" value="Add to wishlist" title="Add to wishlist" class="button-2 add-to-wishlist-button add-to-wishlist-button-6475 active">
    </div>
```

When I changed the code to this using `.find()` it worked:

```
var ele = $("div").find("[data-productid='" + response.productId + "']").find(".wishlist-button");
if (response.addedToWishlist) {
    $(ele).find(".button-2.active").removeClass("active");
    $(ele).find(".remove-from-wishlist-button").addClass("active");
}
```

Like I said none of the code had changed, so it's strange for it to just stop working.
I'm using jquery version 1.10.2
I'm wondering if the `.children()` function got depreciated, or maybe there is something else going on.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I'm concerned because that `.children()` function is used hundreds of times throughout the site.
Thanks

Comment: Your first code block's text is identical to your third code block's text. Also, I don't see anything in your HTML that would match `[data-productid=...`. No, [.children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) is not deprecated, something else must've changed

Comment: Oh sorry will edit

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated that third code block, you can see I changed children to find

Comment: `.children(".wishlist-button")` will select only if a `wishlist-button` is a direct child of something matching `[data-productid='" + response.productId + "']`, but the parent of `wishlist-button` is not shown in the HTML, so it's hard to say

Comment: Oh I see, the problem was with `var ele = $("div").find("[data-productid='" + response.productId + "']").children(".wishlist-button");` there was an element which was sitting between `.wishlist-button` and the attribute selector element from another dev job. Thanks @CertainPerformance would upvote comment but not enough rep :/